# Trying to install pyliblo with pip results in error D8021 invalid numeric argument '/Werror-implicit-function-declaration'

Tags: python, c, visual-c++

I need to install the [pyliblo 0.10.0](https://pypi.org/project/pyliblo/) Python package extension in order to open a project that needs it. When I try installing it running `pip install pyliblo`, I get an error :

```
Installing collected packages: pyliblo
  Running setup.py install for pyliblo ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rapha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7yrf4e9p\\pyliblo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wy9ir57j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    cythoning src/liblo.pyx to src\liblo.c
    building 'liblo' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\liblo.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\liblo.obj -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfatal-errors
    clÿ: Ligne de commande error D8021ÿ: argument num‚rique non valide '/Werror-implicit-function-declaration'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rapha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7yrf4e9p\\pyliblo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wy9ir57j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rapha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7yrf4e9p\pyliblo\
```

I also tried installing pyliblo 0.10.0 without pip, by downloading the .tar.gz file from [their official website](http://das.nasophon.de/pyliblo/), extracting it, and running `./setup.py build` but once again that gives me an error, slightly different but it seems the cause is the same as when trying the pip installation :

```
PS D:\pyliblo-0.10.0> python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'src\liblo.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'liblo' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python37\include -IC:\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\liblo.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\liblo.obj -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfatal-errors
cl : Ligne de commande error D8021 : argument numérique non valide '/Werror-implicit-function-declaration'    
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I'm running a Win10 64bit environment, and I installed all the dependencies for installing pyliblo:

- Python 3.7.3
- Cython
- liblo 0.30

I think I might need to tell the compiler where to find my installation of liblo, but that is just a wild guess.

Thank you for the help, it's been driving me nuts these past few days.

Answer (score -1):

trying using this command:

```
pip install pyliblo==0.10.0
```

Comment: That command gives me the same error as `pip install pyliblo`. I also tried `pip install pyliblo --no-cache-dir` to make sure my cached version is not the problem, but nothing changed.